# Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSString *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, macros, nslog

Anyone:

I want to use one macro to print log, following,

```
#define isaObject(parameter) _Generic((parameter), id: YES, id __strong: YES, default: NO)
#define kNSLog(parameter) do                   \
    {                                          \
        BOOL is = isaObject((parameter));      \
        if (is)                                \
        {                                      \
            NSLog(@"----Yes : %@", parameter); \
        }                                      \
        else                                   \
        {                                      \
            NSLog(@"----No : %d", parameter);  \
        }                                      \
    } while (NO)


int i = 99;
NSString * s = @"abcd";

kNSLog(i);
kNSLog(s);
```

Then, the Compiler gave the warning "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSString *'".

How to modify, Please?

Comment: Not that I recommend it, but look at this page, about halfway down: http://abissell.com/2014/01/16/c11s-_generic-keyword-macro-applications-and-performance-impacts/

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitly cast the parameter to an `int` to avoid that warning:

`NSLog(@"----No : %d", (int)parameter);  \`

Comment: why the down vote? This eliminates the warnings and works properly.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's pretty easy to debug if you perform the macro replacement "by hand".

```
kNSLog(s)
```

expands to

```
do
{                                        
    BOOL is = isaObject((s));
    if (is)                                
    {                                      
        NSLog(@"----Yes : %@", s); 
    }                                      
    else                                   
    {                                      
        NSLog(@"----No : %d", s); // the warning is thrown here
    }                                      
} while (NO)
```

You are explicitly checking the type of the parameter, but you didn't inform the compiler about this, so it see that one branch may actually be trying to print an `NSString` using a `%d` format.

The solution is to explicitly cast the parameter after you check it, so that you provide the compiler with enough information to keep it silent. Specifically

```
    if (is)                                
    {                                      
        NSLog(@"----Yes : %@", parameter); 
    }                                      
    else                                   
    {                                      
        NSLog(@"----No : %d", (int)parameter);
    }
```

Comment: trying to cast to id generates an error under ARC. (but the down vote was NOT  from me.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 #define isaObject(parameter) _Generic((parameter), id: YES, id __strong: YES, default: NO)

  #define kNSLog(parameter) do                  
  {                                          
      BOOL is = isaObject((parameter));      
      if (is)                                
      {                                     
          NSLog(@"----Yes : %@", parameter);
      }                                      
      else                                   
      {                                      
          NSLog(@"----No : %d", parameter);  
      }                                      
  }

   while (NO)
```

plz use ------>

```
NSString * s = @"YES";

kNSLog(s);
```